# How to fill in missing data series?

Tags: microsoft-excel, statistics

I have monthly water quality (Nitrate) measurements from July, 2005 till Oct., 2013 (84 measurements). However, there is no measurements from Oct., 2007 till June, 2009 (21 measurements).

Could you please let me know how can I fill in the missing data using other dataset?

[image]

Comment: Is the data on a different sheet or do you want excel to guess?

Comment: Also, use the dispersion (XY) graph type, not Line.

Comment: @Raystafarian  
Yes, I want excel (or any other software) to guess the missing data (from Dec., 2007 till June 2009; between the highlighted cells).

Answer (score 1):

Pull in the missing data to the end of the column, put the cursor in the "Date" column head, and re-sort the column to incorporate the new data. The sort function is on the Data tab in the "Sort & Filter" section.

[image]

Comment: @P Fitz         
Thanks for your help. I'm sorry I don't understand how can I use Sort and Filter to fill in missing data. I don't have the missing data. I want excel or any other software you recommend to fill in the data from Dec., 2007 till June 2009 (between the highlighted cells).

Comment: Gotcha. I misunderstood what you were trying to do. How are dates determined? It looks like the data set it using the second Tuesday of the month. Is that correct?

Comment: @P Fitz
I have no idea how the dates determined for sampling. I think you're right. In most of the datasets, the sampling date is the second Tuesday of the month https://www.dropbox.com/s/5b4p0zidqp7zfe6/1.jpg.

Comment: @aelwan: It doesn't look like the samples were not taken at regular intervals but, even if they were, where are the nitrate measurements going to come from? You're original questions says you want to "fill in the missing data using other dataset." Where is the other dataset?

Comment: @P Fitz        Many thanks for your help. Apologies for not being clear. I mean, I'd like to fill in the missing data (between the highlighted cells B28:B29 "from Oct., 2007 till June, 2009") using the other dataset (B2:E41 "from July, 2005 till August, 2013"). Hope it is clear now.